# Home Remedies for Oily Skin

Tags: personal-care

I have oily skin both in the summer and the winter.  Because of this, I have a lot of problems with acne, specifically blackheads.  While I wash my skin daily, it is not helping clear the acne up.  Does anyone have any home remedies to help with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had oily skin my whole life, though mine is worse in the summer. I regularly visit a restroom and splash water on my face (which I then blot dry with a towel). Sometimes, instead of splashing water on my face, I wet a paper towel in the sink and gently rub that over my face to wet it, and then I blot it dry with another towel.

I do this several times throughout the day, whenever I feel as though my face is getting a little shiny.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem since ages. I have particularly very oily scalp and forehead.
One home remedy that has worked for me since some time now is **CURD** & lemon juice. I know sounds so simple.

I apply curd with or without lemon juice for 10-15 minutes before I take a shower. Once the curd dries out it takes away complete oil from my scalp and leaves a very soothing effect.

Heres an article you should read for more information [Health Benefits of Curd for Skin](https://www.credihealth.com/blog/health-benefits-of-curd-skin-hair/)